# Expected RBRACKET at line Y, col X. but the brackets are there?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to recreate the following tutotial https://wpbuilt.co/tutorials/how-to-create-beautiful-mobile-menu-using-divi-theme/ but i get the following error "Expected RBRACKET at line Y, col X" both in my theme, cPanel and CSSLint validators. I searched up and down here and till the 10th page of Google for results with no success. 
From what i can pinpoint to problem it appears just after : at padding-top property, and if i remove it it goes after : overflow-y and it doesnt make sense for me.
I would be grateful if someone points me at the direction i am missing.

[CSSLint Result](http://csslint.net/#L59)

```css
.et_slide_in_menu_container.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_animated {
opacity: 1;
background: transparent;
}

.et_slide_in_menu_container.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_animated ul#mobile_menu_slide {
padding: 0 !important;
display: block !important;
}

.et_slide_in_menu_container.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_animated ul#mobile_menu_slide li {
display: inline-block;
}

.et_slide_in_menu_container.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_animated ul#mobile_menu_slide li img, .et_slide_in_menu_container.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_animated ul#mobile_menu_slide li i, .et_slide_in_menu_container.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_animated ul#mobile_menu_slide li svg.svg-inline–fa {
display: none;
}

.et_slide_in_menu_container {
opacity: 1 !important;
}

.et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container {
opacity: 1;
}

.et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container ul#mobile_menu_slide {
opacity: 1!important;
visibility: visible;
display: block!important;
text-align: right;
width: 100%;
padding-right: 22%;
height: initial;
padding-top: 9px;
}

.et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container ul#mobile_menu_slide li {
display: inline-block;
}

.et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container ul#mobile_menu_slide li img, .et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container ul#mobile_menu_slide li i {
display: none;
}

.et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container ul#mobile_menu_slide li {
padding: 0 2%;
}

.et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container ul#mobile_menu_slide li a {
font-size: 17px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

span.mobile_menu_bar.et_pb_header_toggle.et_toggle_fullscreen_menu {
opacity: 0;
}

div#page-container[style=”padding-top: 96px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -43px;”] {}

div#page-container[style=”padding-top: 96px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -43px;”] ul#mobile_menu_slide li a {
font-size: 13px;
}

div#page-container[style=”padding-top: 96px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -43px;”] ul#mobile_menu_slide li {
margin-top: -15px;
}

div#page-container[style=”padding-top: 96px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -43px;”] ul#mobile_menu_slide {
margin-top: -14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe too late,
but you have added content from line 58

```
div#page-container[style=”padding-top: 96px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -43px;”] {}

div#page-container[style=”padding-top: 96px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -43px;”] ul#mobile_menu_slide li a {
font-size: 13px;
}

div#page-container[style=”padding-top: 96px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -43px;”] ul#mobile_menu_slide li {
margin-top: -15px;
}

div#page-container[style=”padding-top: 96px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -43px;”] ul#mobile_menu_slide {
margin-top: -14px;
```